# Download pdf file(Not restricted) from google drive through URL

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, google-drive-api, file-writing

```
import os 
import requests

def download_file(download_url: str, filename: str):
    """
    Download resume pdf file from storage
    @param download_url: URL of reusme to be downloaded
    @type download_url: str
    @param filename: Name and location of file to be stored
    @type filename: str
    @return: None
    @rtype: None
    """
    file_request = requests.get(download_url)
    with open(f'{filename}.pdf', 'wb+') as file:
        file.write(file_request.content)

cand_id = "101"
time_current = "801"
file_location = f"{cand_id}_{time_current}"
download_file("https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf", file_location)
cand_id = "201"
time_current = "901"
download_file("https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1HXnM1lBuoqMzVhZjcwNTAtZWI5OS00ZDg3LWEyMzktNzZmYWY2Y2NhNWQx/view?hl=en&resourcekey=0-5DqnTtXPFvySMiWstuAYdA", file_location)
----------
```

- First file is working perfectly fine (i.e. 101_801.pdf)
- But Second one is not able to open in any pdf reader(i.e.
  201_901.pdf)(Error: We can't open this file).
- What I understood is I'm not able properly read and write for file
  from drive which is open for all. How to read that file and write?
- I can use google drive API but can we have better solution without
  using that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution for it through wget in python. Answering it so that it could help someone in the future.

```
import os
import wget
def download_candidate_resume(email: str, resume_url: str):
    """
    This function is used to download resume from google drive and store on the local system
    @param email: candidate email
    @type email: str
    @param resume_url: url of resume on google drive
    @type resume_url: str
    """
    file_extension = "pdf"
    current_time = datetime.now()
    file_name = f'{email}_{int(current_time.timestamp())}.{file_extension}'
    temp_file_path = os.path.join(
        os.getcwd(),
        f'{email}_{int(current_time.timestamp())}.{file_extension}',
    )
    downloadable_resume_url = re.sub(
        r"https://drive\.google\.com/file/d/(.*?)/.*?\?usp=sharing",
        r"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=\1",
        resume_url,
    )
    wget.download(downloadable_resume_url, out=temp_file_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried out the code and couldnt open the PDF file as well. I suggest trying out [gdown package](https://github.com/wkentaro/gdown). It is easy to use and you can download even large files from google drive. I used it in my class to download  .sql db files (+-20Gb) for my assignments.

If you want to build more on this code, then you should probably check out Drive API. It is a well documented fast API.

Comment: Tried same with gdown but error remains same

`
import gdown
url = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B1HXnM1lBuoqMzVhZjcwNTAtZWI5OS00ZDg3LWEyMzktNzZmYWY2Y2NhNWQx'
output = 'hello.pdf'
gdown.download(url, output, quiet=False)
`